# Nodeos folder non-existed after eosio installation with brew

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code, macos

I am trying to install and run an EOS node on macos.

I installed eosio with brew.

I used

```
brew tap eosio/eosio
brew install eosio
```

Everything went alright. But after installation the following folder was supposed to be created `/usr/local/eosio` which it did not.

Also, from what I know I should have a folder in my Application Support with the nodeos that was installed with eosio ( since  I want to edit the configuration file for nodeos ). However, I don't have the following folders.
`/Users/[user]/Library/Library Support/eosio/nodeos`

**Note that `nodeos --help` works, as well as `cleos --help`**

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or the folders have been changed.

Comment: Can you try ```which nodeo``` or  ```which cleos```  ? This should return the path to your installation.

Comment: @TeeAttack42 Thanks for the response. So `which nodeos` returns `/usr/local/bin/nodeos` and `cleos` is as well in the same folder. I tried `which eosio` with the hope that it would show a path but it returned nothing.

Comment: I think I found the eosio folder, it's in `/usr/local/Cellar/eosio/2.1.0/bin` which contains the nodeos, cleos, keosd binaries. However, I still can't find the config for nodeos which was supposed to be in Librabry Support.

Comment: Problem solved.  After I spun a node with nodeos, the eosio folder in Library Support seemed to magically appear.